# UIButton will not center in UITableViewCell when manually centered

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, uitableview

I am working on a small exercise for myself and I am running into a small issue that perhaps someone can offer some assitance on. I have the `TableViewCell` setup to expand when tapping on the cell. This works great. My issue, is that the `UIButton` that I have within the `TableViewCell` will not center.

**Note: I am not using `Auto Layout` in this application.**

I have a `ViewController` which currently handles my main view. I have a XIB that I created and I have designed my TableViewCell for this exercise in.

[image: custom xib]

Looking at the layout of the XIB, everything looks like it should however when I run the app in the simulator, you can see that the `UIButton` shifts to the left slightly.

[image: simulator]

I have the `Auto Resizing` attributes setup as such, as if I do not, the `UIButton` is pushed into the `TableViewCell` which is not what I want.

[image: auto resizing]

Any idea why this does not center correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select your button and horizontally center it.

[image]

Comment: When viewing the `XIB` there are no constraint options like the `ViewController` itself has.

Comment: You can set it programmatically  
`myButton.frame.origin = CGPointMake(self.view.frame.width/2 - myButton.frame.size.width/2,self.view.frame.size.height/2 - myButton.frame.size.height/2);`

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it may not work( I had the same problem). Just do it programmatically and forget about this.

For example:

```
    UIButton * btn = [UIButton alloc] init];
    btn.frame.origin = CGPointMake(
    self.view.frame.width/2       - btn.frame.size.width/2,
    self.view.frame.size.height/2 - btn.frame.size.height/2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Reading other posts, it seems that Arda's response should have worked but it was not working for me.

What I did was, enable `Auto Layout` on the `XIB` as well as `Size Classes`. I then realized that my XIB was not wide enough as it was not using `Size Classes` before which seemed to cause things to shift a bit within the `TableViewCell`. A few extra tweaks here in there and in my code and things are good.

Now when I run the app, things look correct.